# Sort and group by same key once

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, python-itertools

I want to group a list with urls by its [TLDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain)

My code looks like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from tldextract import extract

urls = sorted(urls, key=lambda x: extract(x).suffix)
grouped_urls = groupby(urls, key=lambda x: extract(x).suffix)
```

The problem is that I call method `extract` 2*n times( `where n == len(urls)`), first n times when sorting, and second n times when grouping.
Is it possible to make it n times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first add the suffix as a tuple, you can then sort and groupby without needing to recompute it as follows:

```
from itertools import groupby
from tldextract import extract

urls = ["www.example.com", "www.mytest.org", "www.test.com", "www.abc.com"]
urls = [(extract(url).suffix, url) for url in urls]

for k, g in groupby(sorted(urls), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    print k, list(g)
```

In this example you would get:

```
com [('com', 'www.abc.com'), ('com', 'www.example.com'), ('com', 'www.test.com')]
org [('org', 'www.mytest.org')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending all how large your list of urls is, you could get some speed up if you built a list of all the extracted suffices once, and then use indexing on the list of indices to *sort* and *group*:

```
from itertools import groupby, count
from tldextract import extract

c1, c2 = count(), count()

lst = [extract(x).suffix for x in urls]
urls = sorted(urls, key=lambda _: lst[next(c1)])
grouped_urls = groupby(urls, key=lambda _: lst[next(c2)])
```

The drawback of this is that you'll be doing `O(1)` indexing for `2n` times, and the speed up would be more than marginal if the total time for `extract(x)` on the list is far more than the time taken to index the new list.